# scrapy callback in parse not called

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying out scrapy, and got a bit stuck. I would expect this script to run the callback.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider

class ASpider(Spider):
    name = 'myspider'
    allowed_domains = ['wikipedia.org','en.wikipedia.org']
    start_urls = ['https://www.wikipedia.org/']

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.css("a::attr('href')").extract()
        for url in urls:
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            print("url\t",url)
            scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.my_callback)


    def my_callback(self,response):
        print("callback called")
```

Output from calling this:

```
2016-05-31 16:21:26 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2016-05-31 16:21:26 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {}
2016-05-31 16:21:26 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2016-05-31 16:21:26 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.chunked.ChunkedTransferMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2016-05-31 16:21:26 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2016-05-31 16:21:26 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2016-05-31 16:21:26 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-05-31 16:21:26 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-05-31 16:21:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.wikipedia.org/> (referer: None)
url  https://en.wikipedia.org/
url  https://es.wikipedia.org/
url  https://ja.wikipedia.org/

(Long list of similar urls)

url  https://meta.wikimedia.org/
2016-05-31 16:21:27 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-05-31 16:21:27 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 215,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 18176,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 14, 21, 27, 240038),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 14, 21, 26, 328888)}
2016-05-31 16:21:27 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

It does not run the callback. Why is this and what needs to be changed for the callback to work?

Comment: you are missing the `yield` before `Request`

Comment: `yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.my_callback)`

Comment: @eLRuLL Thanks, I feel quite stupid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A spider callback has to yield a request, item or (i think) a dict.

> In the callback function, you parse the response (web page) and return either dicts with extracted data, Item objects, Request objects, or an iterable of these objects. Those Requests will also contain a callback (maybe the same) and will then be downloaded by Scrapy and then their response handled by the specified callback.

From [the scrapy docs (point 2)](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=callback).